# I could not create a new project " Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath' "

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, gradle

I'm using windows 10 and Android studio version 3.2.1

I'm facing tow problems :

1- when I'm trying to update or install packages in SDK manger I get this message :

> Installation did not complete successfully. see the IDE log for
>   details

2- when I create a new project I get this error :

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could
>   not find any version that matches
>   com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version
>   that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.

---

> build.gradle(module) :

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.one-click.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I tried a lot of solution but with no benefit, hope you help me

Answer (score 0):

change   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+' to below and also change the  compileSdkVersion 29 to  compileSdkVersion 28 and  targetSdkVersion 29 to  targetSdkVersion 28

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

Comment: It will work correctly and also make sure that you've downloaded API 28. just open SDK manager and there you'll see it, if not downloaded then downloade it